# Hide a UIImageView - Setting the Width Constraint Constant at 0

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a `UIImageView` inside a `CollectionViewCell` subclass. On the `CollectionViewCell` XIB I have an image.

Sometimes I need to hide the imageView. To achieve this in the cell configuration method I'm hiding the UIImageView, setting the width constraint to 0.

```
if (showImageView) {
    self.imageViewWidthConstraint.constant = self.defaultImageViewWidthConstraint;
    self.imageViewUsernameLabelHorizontalConstraint.constant = self.defaultImageViewUsernameLabelHorizontalConstraint;
} else {
    self.imageViewWidthConstraint.constant = 0;
    self.imageViewUsernameLabelHorizontalConstraint.constant = 0;
}
```

The problem is that in iOS7 the app is crashing for a unsatisfiable constraint

```
    Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170890090 H:[UIImageView:0x1456dd970(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170890090 H:[UIImageView:0x1456dd970(0)]>
```

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong. I double-checked my XIB, but everything is fine. There is some rule that i don't know about the constraint constant change that i don't know?

I tried to set the constraint to 0 in the XIB and i see that i'm not breaking other constraints. In that case the app runs correctly.

Comment: Nah there's no mystery. Probably you have two width constraints. Did you create UIImage view programmatically? Checked translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints?

Comment: There is only one width constraint on the UIImageView. If i change it to 0 in the Interface Builder i don't get errors or warning. The constraints list is not showing any autoresizingMask related constraints. From what i see there is only one constraint involved.

Comment: OK must be something else maybe a leading or trailing to superview. There's definitely two constraints disagreeing; otherwise you wouldn't get that exception. Are you sure that Auto Layout is causing the crash? Could we see the full crash log?